# Displaying data from database to select tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

I want to update the data from database using select tag but the problem is I don't know how to import data to select so that when I click the Edit button, the data will be imported. So far, I imported the data to the textbox. The only problem is the select tag.

[image]

**PHP CODE:**

```
echo "<div class='col-3'>";
echo "<div class='card'>";
echo "<div class='row'>";
echo "<div class='col-2'>";
echo "<h6 class='card-title'>".$row['project_name']."</h6>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-2'>";
echo "<div class='card-setting'><i class='fa fa-gear'></i></div>";
echo "<div id='card-setting-dropdown' class='card-dropdown-content'>";
echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu' id='btn-edit'>Edit Project</button>";
echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu'>Delete Project</button>";
echo "<button class='card-dropdown-menu'>Add Task</button>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='row'>";
echo "<div class='col-2'>";
echo "<label  class='project-details'>".$row['department']."</label>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-2'>";
echo "<label class='project-details' style='float:right;'>Priority: <span style='color:".$color."'>".$row['priority']."</span></label>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='pr-task-data'>";
echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Tasks</label>";
echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_2."</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Completed</label>";
echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_3."</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-l'>";
echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>In-Progress</label>";
echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_4."</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='pr-task-summary-r'>";
echo "<label class='pr-task-title'>Not Completed</label>";
echo "<p class='pr-task-details'>".$count_5."</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='progress'>";
echo "<div class='progress-bar' style='width:".$percent."%;'>";
echo "<label class='progress-bar-percent'>".$percent."%</label>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id='modal_2' class='modal fade'>";
echo "<div class='modal-dialog'>";
echo "<div class='modal-content'>";
echo "<div class='modal-header'>";
echo "<h6 class='modal-title'>Add Project</h6>";
echo "<button type='button' class='close_2'>x</button>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='modal-body'>";
echo "<form autocomplete='off' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' id='".$row['project_id']."'>";
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Program</label>";
echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Program' name='program' id='program_2' class='form-control'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Project Name</label>";
echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Project Name' name='pname' id='pname' class='form-control'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Project Description</label>";
echo "<input type='text' placeholder='Description' name='description' id='description' class='form-control'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Department</label>";
echo "<select class='form-control' id='department' name='department'>";
echo "<option value=''>Department</option>";
echo "<option value='Executive Department'>Executive Department</option>";
echo "<option value='CCA Department'>CCA Department</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='form-group'>";
echo "<label class='form-control-label'>Priority</label>";
echo "<select class='form-control' id='priority' name='priority'>";
echo "<option value=''>Priority</option>";
echo "<option value='Low'>Low</option>";
echo "<option value='Medium'>Medium</option>";
echo "<option valie='High'>High</option>";
echo "<option valie='High'>High</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='modal-footer'>";
echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-update' name='update'>Update</button>";
echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'>Close</button>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: You do know that you don't have to echo _every line of HTML_ individually, right?

Comment: i know sir i did that so i wont be confused. its just a scratch code i will polish my code after i can import $row['department'] to <select> tag

Comment: Echoing every line of html makes it extremely confusing to literally everyone except you I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Is the chosen option not being saved in the database? Do you want to generate all options from a list in an array that comes from the database? Do you want the 1 option that matches the current value in your database record to be automatically "selected" when you open the form? If so, I have a function that does most of that.

Comment: I doing CRUD operations. Now, when I click the edit button, all of the data of a specific row will be displayed inside the text box (please see image) and select tag. No problem with transferring the data into the text box value the problem is transferring the the data to a select tag. The transferred data should be the selected data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<option value='Low' ".($row['priority']=='Low' ? 'selected' : '').">Low</option>";
```

add "selected" if database value is exactly same with option's value.

Comment: add selected like above to every options except having empty value.
e.g. Low, Medium, High in priority

*** because of selected by value, do not use duplicated value
*** valie(x) value(o)